Bounds for number of 1s in a rank r matrix
I am interested in binary matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  For  $n \times n$ binary matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of rank $r$, are there known upper bounds for the number of ones in such matrices?
For rank 1 matrices the upper bound is reached by the all ones matrix.  The lower bound is reached with the all zeros matrix with one element being set to 1. So the upper and lower bounds are $(n^2, 1)$.
The lower bounds always appear to be $r$ by taking the first $r$ rows of the identity matrix and filling the rest of zeros.
It is the upper bounds which I don't have any idea how to tackle.

What have you tried? The lower bound should be obvious. The rank $n$ case for upper bound should be reasonably easy (maybe?). Can you state those results, or your attempts?

@CalvinLin I added all that I know.

Note that your construction for rank $1$ is wrong, since the all-$1$ matrix also has rank $1$.

@SharkyKesa Thank you.

Note that you can construct a rank $r$ matrix with $r$ elements along the diagonal being $1$, and the rest being $0$, giving you a lower bound of $r$ (you can observe you can’t get lower since columns of $0$s cannot contribute to rank).
For an upper bound, you can kind of invert this construction. Consider a matrix with $r-1$ elements along the diagonal being $0$, and the rest being $1$. Then this matrix has rank $r$ as well, giving you an upper bound of $n^2-r+1$ (you can observe you can’t get larger since columns containing only $1$s can only contribute $1$ to the rank altogether).
Hence, you the number of $1$s is bounded by $r$ and $n^2-r+1$.

This is a very nice and simple solution. Thank you.
